# How to serve couple containers with domain names with Docker NGINX image

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I need to host multiple sites with my docker-machine in future, but know i'm trying to launch it on localhost.

The main purpose is to get certain site, of course I need to start with my `/etc/hosts` file on OS X, below is listing:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost

127.0.0.1     dev.proling.ru
127.0.0.1     dev.vshvetsov.ru
```

This configuration provide for me access to sites with chosen domains independently of DNS settings. Now I'll show my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'

services:
  mysql:
    build: mysql/
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    container_name: mysql
  vshvetsov:
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    build: vshvetsov/
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    restart: always
    container_name: vshvetsov
  proling:
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    build: proling/
    ports:
      - 8003:80
    restart: always
    container_name: proling
  nginx:
    depends_on:
      - proling
      - vshvetsov
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
     - "80:80"
    volumes:
     - ./nginx/volume:/etc/nginx
    container_name: nginx
volumes:
    mysql_data:
```

Both site containers works perfectly on `localhost:8000` and `localhost:8003` and below is my `nginx/volume` folder tree:

```
volume
    ├── conf.d
    │   ├── default.conf
    │   ├── proling.ru
    │   └── vshvetsov.ru
    ├── fastcgi_params
    ├── koi-utf
    ├── koi-win
    ├── mime.types
    ├── modules -> /usr/lib/nginx/modules
    ├── nginx.conf
    ├── scgi_params
    ├── uwsgi_params
    └── win-utf
```

So the only way to impact on my NGINX configuration is to put `.conf` files in `conf.d` directory and below are both of them:

dev.proling.ru

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name  www.proling.ru;
    rewrite ^ http://proling.ru$request_uri? permanent; #301 redirect
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name proling.ru *.proling.ru;

        location / {

            proxy_pass http://proling;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

            access_log /var/log/nginx/proling.ru-access.log;
        }
}
```

And dev.vshvetsov.ru

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name www.vshvetsov.ru vshvetsov.ru dev.vshvetsov.ru;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://vshvetsov;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/vshvetsov.ru-access.log;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved with rename nginx config files in `conf.d`. They must end with `.conf` extension because `nginx.conf` have this string by default:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

Of course I can mount or copy our config if it's more handy, but I prefer default path.